# SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, internet-explorer-9

I am getting this very bizzare error. I have a serverside datatable that is working in both Chrome and Firefox but not IE. The error I am getting is SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'.

```
this.dataTable = $(this.table).dataTable( {
    'bFilter': false,
    'bLengthChange': false,
    'bProcessing': true,
    'bServerSide': true,
    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
    'bSort': false,
    'iDisplayLength' : 10,
    'sAjaxSource': this.restEndpoint,
    'fnServerData': function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
        aoData.push({'name' : 'vendorCode', value : vendorCode.val()});
        aoData.push({'name' : 'invoiceNumber', value : invoiceNumber.val()});
        oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
            'type' : 'post',
            'url': sUrl,
            'data': aoData,
            'success': function(data) {fnCallback(data);},
            'cache': true
        } );
    },
    'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {

    }
});
```

The error disappears when I remove 'data': aoData, in the fnServerData function.

```
    'fnServerData': function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
        aoData.push({'name' : 'vendorCode', value : vendorCode.val()});
        aoData.push({'name' : 'invoiceNumber', value : invoiceNumber.val()});
        oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
            'type' : 'post',
            'url': sUrl,
            'success': function(data) {fnCallback(data);},
            'cache': true
        } );
    },
```

I inspected the aoData variable and I didn't see any semicolons or strange characters

Comment: I see nothing wrong so far but does it make a difference if you put quote around value. like aoData.push({'name' : 'vendorCode', 'value' : vendorCode.val()});

Comment: @SSA, that didn't make any difference. The error is still happening.